# Can not deploy a project on Jboss because of a Dozer class not found

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, classnotfoundexception, dozer

Hi I'm using Eclipse on a EJB3 project, struts2 and hibernate.Server is JBoss 7.1. Everything worked fine.
Then I've installed Dozer 5.2.2,***and added that to the build path*** (it shows in "referenced libraries" folder, and I've checked in the "configure build path" menu as well) 
It works fine in my Junit test cases.
The problem is that when I try to deploy the EJB project , I get an error :

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper** from [Module "deployment.EJBprofile.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanx for your help

Comment: What kind of deployment is this, EAR, WAR, etc.?

Comment: Hi james, its War for the web client and Jar for the ejb

Comment: Is it all packaged in an EAR? There is likely a dependency link that needs to get made.

Comment: No , should I recreate it with EAR packaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the Dozer as a module if you need it for both your EJB and your WAR. You could also package everything into an EAR and put the Dozer library in the `EAR/lib` directory.

Also have a look at how [class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) works.

Comment: :) I just need Dozer on the EJB side since I use Hibernate to retrive objects with collections and get Errors if i don't clone them.
I will try both solutions you provided.
To install as a module, I created directories "org" / "dozer" /"main" , added there dozer-5.2.2.jar and created "module.xml" file with :
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.dozer">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="dozer-5.2.2"/>
  </resources>
</module>
 but does not work. I will try with the EAR solution

Comment: You would also need to add it as a dependency in your `MANIFEST.MF` in your EJB jar.

Comment: Solved :D
I added the dozer jar to the lib (used right click... add module... in eclipse) I had to add all the libs this way. I also added CDI capabilities to the project. dozer works fine ^^
Thanks a lot James, I'm working on this project to get my diploma , so it's great help!!